# Why doesn't my JavaScript function call another function?

Tags: javascript

In html I call a javascript function setMode(int), which works as expected. This function completes paramter input and should call an other javascript function mode(String) again. Problem is, mode(String) isn't called.

```
function setMode(mode) {
  mode("?set=" + String(mode));
}

function mode(parameter) {
  parameter = (typeof parameter === 'undefined') ? '' : parameter;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      switch (parseInt(this.responseText)) {
        case 0:
          document.getElementById("radio-auto2").checked = true;
          break;
        case 1:
          document.getElementById("radio-open2").checked = true;
          break;
        case 2:
          document.getElementById("radio-close2").checked = true;
          break;
        default:
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "mode" + String(parameter), true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: `mode("?set=" + String(mode))` ... are you passing a function to `setMode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function parameter `mode` hides the higher-scoped function `mode(parameter)`. JavaScript doesn't keep a dictionary of names and infer which one you meant to use by how it's being used, so there's no way for it to know that the first `mode` you write was supposed to be a different one than the second `mode`. You have to make this distinction yourself.

The simplest solution is to change the name of the parameter or the name of the function so one isn't hiding the other. I think `mode` is a terrible name for a function, as it describes nothing about what the function does. Try renaming it to `submitMode` or something else.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the name of the variable so the function and variable are not called the same thing